# How to ask a question section on Politics?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am wondering if Politics.SE should have a section similar to [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from Stackoverflow.

I have seen that many persons reviewing there are linking to this page when explaining what is wrong with a question.

Of course, Politics is less technical than SO, so it is harder to judge if a question is fit or not, but I think some guidelines can be drawn.

One possible topic in How to ask could be: try to provide as much context is possible and relevant. E.g. [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23366/what-public-office-did-prince-philip-hold) provides little context (one must search to check for references for the claims), while [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/23339/why-didnt-trump-veto-h-r-3364-since-he-considers-it-significantly-flawed-wit) and [this](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/19431/why-does-the-eu-invest-so-much-in-biodiesel-if-it-has-a-very-low-return-on-inves) provide much more context.

Other topics may include [asking to prove a point](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2828/is-it-okay-to-ask-a-question-to-prove-a-point), [open-ended questions](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/how-to-handle-open-ended-questions-seeking-opinion-based-answers) etc.

**Question:** Should we have a How to ask section on Politics.SE?

Comment: The Politics.SE help center [does have a "how to ask" section](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/asking). But it only includes the default articles. The only section we can (and did) edit is [What topics can I ask about here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: @Philipp - yes, but MCVE model of a single page ("crash course") seems better to me. I bet most of the users never read those sections, but might read something more concise, especially when being downvoted or having questions closed with a link to such a section.

Comment: I'd agree that most of our Help Center isn't useful. Good luck getting these pages changed. I've also tried to [generate some motion](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2898/should-we-change-the-help-center-to-mention-that-political-theory-is-on-topic/2909#2909), but it doesn't seem to get anywhere.